# JQuery getJSON / PHP returning data and displaying the data

Tags: php, jquery, getjson

I have a login using getJSON and PHP.

Right now all it does it checks if the user and password is valid but if it is I want to pass further information to the client.

Right now on the server side I do this:

```
if ($result->num_rows) {            
    echo '{"response":{"error": "1"}}';         
} else {
    echo '{"response":{"error": "0"}}';
}
```

and on the client side I have this:

```
if (json.response.error == "1") {
    data = "Welcome "+username;
    alert(data);
} else {
    // Login fail
    data = "Wrong Username/Password";
    alert(data);
}
```

So basically it's just checking.

How can I pass some more information from the server to the client?

Update: I've changed the code to this but it's now not working:

Server:

```
if ($result->num_rows) {

//echo '{"response":{"error": "1"}}';
$data = array(
'response'     => array(
'error'    => 1,
),
'someData'     => 'data';
);
print json_encode($data);
}
```

Client:

```
$.getJSON("server.php", {username:username,password:password},function(data)
{

alert('hello');
var json = JSON.parse(data);
alert(json.responseCode);


});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the server side, You can create an array containing all the data you need and then send it from the server to the client using [json_encode()](http://php.net/en/json_encode) :

```
$data = array(
    'response'     => array(
        'error'    => 1,
    ),
    'someData'     => 'data',
    ...
);
print json_encode($data);
```

And on the client side :

```
var json = JSON.parse(data);
alert(json.response.error);
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: I've added it like this but it not longer log's in: echo '{"response":{"error": "1"}}';
$data = array(
'responseCode' => 1,
'someData'     => 'data';
);
print json_encode($data);

Comment: I've edited the response, but you also need to remove your `echo`.

Comment: I've removed the echo from the server code and the client side looks like this:

Comment: var json = JSON.parse(data);alert(json.responseCode);}..but no alerts happening...any ideas?

Comment: The structure of the php array changed, so the structure of the javascript array changed too.

Comment: Seriously, read a bit what the code is doing, and try to understand it.

Comment: I understand what it's doing but it's just not working for some reason...no alerts

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `jQuery.parseJSON(json)` where json  here is a well formed json string.

From the documentation:

*It takes a well-formed JSON string and returns the resulting JavaScript object.*

So you have to parse the string first to a javascript object.

```
var json = $.parseJSON(data); // data is the json string
if (json.response.error == "1") {
   data = "Welcome "+username;
   alert(data);
} else {
   // Login fail
   data = "Wrong Username/Password";
   alert(data);
}
```